A Cloudinary Cloud name is required, please make sure NEXT_PUBLIC_CLOUDINARY_CLOUD_NAME is set and configured in your environment
I'm new to programming and working importing an image from cloudinary in next14.js but got this error. How do I resolve it?
Error: A Cloudinary Cloud name is required, please make sure NEXT_PUBLIC_CLOUDINARY_CLOUD_NAME is set and configured in your environment.
`"use client";
import { CldImage } from 'next-cloudinary';
<CldImage src='https://res.cloudinary.com/digotb1jl/image/upload/v1727703580/samples/imagecon-group.jpg' width={500} height={500} crop={{type: 'auto', source: true}}/>
`

You need to provide your Cloudinary credentials in the .env file - you can check out this Cloudinary sample project for reference.
